# Android ViewModel Observers not working until orientation change (ViewModel works, but changing to LiveData causes the problem)

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I have been trying to make an app that will double and triple my values into 2 textViews, and when I used viewModel, it survived all config changes. When I changed the result type to MutableLiveData the textView values don't change until I rotate the phone, after pressing my button. Here's my MainFragment

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {
private var _binding: MainFragmentBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

companion object {
    fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
}

private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = MainFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MainViewModel::class.java]

    binding.textView.text = viewModel.getResults().toString()
    binding.textView2.text = viewModel.getResults().toString()


    val resultsObserver = Observer<List<Float?>>{
        binding.textView.text = it[0].toString()
        binding.textView2.text = it[1].toString()
    }

    viewModel.getResults().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, resultsObserver)

    binding.action.setOnClickListener {

        if(binding.editTextNumberDecimal.text.isNotEmpty()){
            viewModel.setValues(binding.editTextNumberDecimal.text.toString())
        }else{
            binding.textView.text = getString(R.string.no)
            binding.textView2.text = getString(R.string.no1)
        }
    }
}
```

}

And here is my viewModel

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
private var input = ""

private var doubleValue = 0f

private var tripleValue = 0f

fun setValues(value: String){
    input = value
    doubleValue = input.toFloat() * 2
    tripleValue = input.toFloat() * 3
}

fun getResults(): MutableLiveData<List<Float?>> = MutableLiveData(listOf(doubleValue, tripleValue))
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO. A LiveData is a value holder, and in order to use it you must observe it, and then update its value. I suggest you spend a few minutes reading [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) that contains a simple example at the bottom. In short, you need to do `mutableld.postValue(xxx)` (for e.g.). And the observed liveData will trigger.

Comment: Lots of things cleared up, thank you! Also, I appreciate the welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MutableLiveData` won't react automatically to the changed values you set via `setValues`.
You will need to update the values inside of your `MutableLiveData` explicitly via `setValue()`.

To achive this, I'd suggest you to store your `MutableLiveData` in a field of your `ViewModel` to be able to access it.

For example like this:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var input = ""

    private var doubleValue = 0f

    private var tripleValue = 0f

    private val results = MutableLiveData(listOf(doubleValue, tripleValue))

    fun setValues(value: String){
        input = value
        doubleValue = input.toFloat() * 2
        tripleValue = input.toFloat() * 3
        // This updates the value inside your LiveData
        results.value = listOf(doubleValue, tripleValue)
    }

    fun getResults(): LiveData<List<Float?>> = results
}
```

Comment: `fun getResults(): MutableLiveData<List<Float?>> = results` -> `fun getResults(): LiveData<List<Float?>> = results` ;) You should not expose the "mutable" liveData.

Comment: Thanks @jodoll. I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet but your solution worked so bless up! Cheers

Comment: @MartinMarconcini You're absolutely right, I tried to keep the changes minimal, but I'll add this one.